# Create User in the backend on channel form submission

Tags: members, channel, channel-form, registration, users

I have a channel **Retailers** with channel fields: **Title**, **Email**, **Country**, etc..

On the front end the visitors on the site can enter information in this channel (if they are retailers) via the **channel form**.

```
{exp:channel:form channel="retailers"}
```

The site is still under construction and we want all visitors that are retailers to "register" or enter some data about themself that is going to be later displayed.

Is there any way to create a **User/Member** in the backend(using some of the channel form data) after submitting this information in the channel **Retailers**?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using an add-on like [Zoo Visitor](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zoo-visitor), which ties users to channel entries. There is a tag for a registration form which could include any other fields you wanted for the channel entry as well as creating a user.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [extension hook](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/module/channel_form/index.html) to manually create a new member in the `exp_members` table. Just grab the data from the form and do all your work in your extension.

You'll have to write the SQL queries yourself using the CodeIgniter API, but I've seen it work.